# d3 match element id to update existing item

Tags: d3.js

Based on the first answer I did more research and came up with my solution to the problem.  I am including the update function: The mention of keying the data was useful.

```
function update(data) {
    var agent = canvas.selectAll(".node.agent")
        //sets all elements to false for the class before the update
        .classed("newCall", false)
       .data(data, function (d) {
           // the key is either an element id or an id from the data
           var myId = d.id ? d.id : this.id;
           //console.log("data key: " + d.id + " element id: " + this.id + " new: " + d.newCall);
           return myId;
       }).classed("newCall", function (d) {
           var f = d.newCall ? d.newCall : false;
           //console.log(this.id + " " + f )
           return f;
       });

    agent.enter().append("g")
    .classed("newCall", function (d) {

           return d.newCall ? d.newCall : false;
       });

    agent.exit().classed("newCall", function (d) {
      //  console.log(d);
        return false;
    });

};
```

I have this html, generated by data using d3.  I have another data source that I want to use to modify that html.  below is the function I want to use to class the elements so I can change them in real time using css.  What I am trying to do is match the id of the element with one generated by the new data. I have the function logging the id of the elements on the canvas. I am not sure how to check the id's against the data passed to the update chart function. The each(d) is the existing data. The data parameter is what I need to do the enter and update on...

```
function updateChart(data) {

   var sel = canvas.selectAll(".agent")
        .each(function (d) {
   // these are the id's I need to check against 
   // the data                
   console.log(d3.select(this).attr("id"));


        })
};
};
```

I found this and it helped me iterate over existing elements:

[SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27405377/iterate-over-already-created-nodes-in-d3js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that this is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem): you probably don't need any of that cumbersome `each()` code, you can do what you want using a [key function](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/master/README.md#selection_data) in your `data` method.

However, since you didn't post your data or a (minimal) running version of your code, I'll address your specific question regarding the `each()` method.

My suggestion is first getting the `id` of `this` element...

```
var id = d3.select(this).attr("id");
```

... and filtering the `data` argument accordingly:

```
data.filter(function(d) {
    return d.id === id;
})[0]
```

Here is a very basic demo, where the size of the circles are changed according to their IDs:

```js
var data = [{
  id: "foo",
  size: 20
}, {
  id: "bar",
  size: 40
}, {
  id: "baz",
  size: 10
}];

var svg = d3.select("svg");

updateChart(data);

function updateChart(data) {

  var sel = svg.selectAll(".agent")
    .each(function() {
      var id = d3.select(this).attr("id");
      d3.select(this).transition()
        .duration(1000)
        .attr("r", function() {
          return data.filter(function(d) {
            return d.id === id;
          })[0].size;
        })
    })
};
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg>
  <circle class="agent" id="foo" cx="50" cy="50" r="5" fill="teal"></circle>
  <circle class="agent" id="bar" cx="150" cy="50" r="5" fill="teal"></circle>
  <circle class="agent" id="baz" cx="250" cy="50" r="5" fill="teal"></circle>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks!   If you have a chance can you show the same example using the key function you mentioned? I would love to ask the right question instead if  I can.

Comment: Ask a new question with your data in an [MCVE].

Comment: Thank you!! I figured it out with  the filter...the answer was spot on.